# Input is 4, n is integer, comprehension list containing squares of integers from 1 till n^2,print list

Tags: list, list-comprehension

You are given an integer 'n'. Create a list comprehension containing the squares of the integers from 1 till n^2( including 1 and n), and print the list.

Example
If the input is 4,the output should be a list as follows
[1,4,9,16]

Comment: Can you show where do you get stuck - if you have tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this code:

```
>>> range(1, n+1)    # get the range from 1 to n, refresh how range works
range(1, 5)

>>> squares = [n*n for n in range(1, n+1)]
>>> squares
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use below method; I tried this and got the appropriate results.

```
n = int(input())

squares_list = [n**2 for n in range(1,n+1)]

print(squares_list)
```